# inserting Date Time to sql server 2008 using c#

Tags: c#, sql-server

I get `failed to convert parameter value from a string to a datetime` error, I have a text box in which the user should insert a date, my code is:

```
SqlConnection Con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\targil3.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True");
SqlDataAdapter adapt = new SqlDataAdapter();
adapt.InsertCommand = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO tblEmployee VALUES (@employeeNumber, @employeePrivateName, @employeeFamilyName ,@city, @street, @houseNo, @phoneNumber, @birthDate, @startWorkingDate)", Con);
adapt.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@employeeNumber", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = textBox1.Text;
adapt.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@employeePrivateName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = textBox2.Text;
adapt.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@employeeFamilyName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = textBox3.Text;
adapt.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@city", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = textBox4.Text;
adapt.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@street", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = textBox5.Text;
adapt.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@houseNo", SqlDbType.Int).Value = textBox6.Text;
adapt.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@phoneNumber", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = textBox7.Text;
adapt.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@birthDate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = textBox8.Text;
adapt.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@startWorkingDate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = textBox9.Text;

Con.Open();
adapt.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
Con.Close();
```

How do I get it to work?

Comment: So what text have you tried to convert to `DateTime`?

Comment: a date format 2000/05/22, for example

Comment: the default is `yyyy-MM-dd hh-mm-ss`

Comment: It depends on how your database is running (language). Can accept dates in the format YYYY-MM-DD or DD-MM-YYYY, try converting the format using .ToString("YYYY-MM-DD") for example.

Comment: use datetimepicker and convert date to sql format.

Answer (score 2):

I guess the problem is here:

```
adapt.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@birthDate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = textBox8.Text;
```

You are specifying type to be of `DateTime` type and you are passing it a string. Try converting your string value to `DateTime` type object like:

```
adapt.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@birthDate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value 
        = Convert.ToDateTime(textBox8.Text);
```

You may look into `DateTime.ParseExact` or `DateTime.TryParseExact`, if you get format exception during parsing. See: [Customized DateTime Formats](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx).

Comment: `AddWithValue` uses a string instead of a `DateTime`. A simple `DateTime.Parse("2013/05/22")` should work (or better `TryParse...)`.

Comment: @TimSchmelter, removed that part :), I wasn't sure about it

Comment: Thank you, however when I use your solution i get "String or binary data would be truncated. The statement has been terminated."

Comment: it depends on the default datetime format of the machine the code runs on. so specifying exact format string is good idea.

Comment: @user2023203, see : [DateTime.ParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx)

Comment: @user2023203: If you use the `DateTime` parameter you don't need to take care of formats since `DateTime` has no format. The string parameter is dangerous.

Comment: @user2023203, convert your textbox value to `DateTime` type object and then pass that to SQL server

Answer (score 0):

you could ideally set the adapt.InsertCommand to a variable and use it instead (both perf. and less typing)

assuming you guaranty the correct format for the text of textbox, change the lines with datetime parameters like this

```
adapt.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@birthDate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DateTime.Parse(textBox8.Text, "yyyy/MM/dd");
```